# What is the gender of the giant dragon?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

What is the gender of the giant dragon in [*How to Train Your Dragon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0892769/)? Astrid refers to it as the Queen, but Hiccup calls it a he and him several times in their battle with it. The movie is not clear if the dragon is male or female, and the sites I searched about it were just as cryptic. So what is the gender of the giant dragon?

Comment: As per [this link](http://howtotrainyourdragon.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Death) she is female.

Comment: @Mistu4u top says *maybe* a female, thought to be. bottom (under trivia) says it could also have been referring to a male from one of the books. So that link doesnt really clear things up

Comment: The Red-Death is a male in all likelihood. Astrid refers to it as the *Queen* because it lived in a hive like lair where the smaller dragons where forced to bring food and feed it. This is quite similar to the behavior of [Queen-Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_ant#An_established_colony) and [Queen-Bee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_bee#Daily_life_for_the_queen).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A conclusive answer has not been found either in the film, the book or any fan wikia. However speculation presents it as a **female**, for *queen* of the nest.

[Red Death - How to Train Your Dragon wikia](http://howtotrainyourdragon.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Death)

> The gender is possibly female, as it is known as the queen of the Mountain Nest of the dragons.

The rest of the sources and material simply refer to it as *it*.

Comment: Hiccup clearly calls the dragon the **queen** of the nest.-

Answer (score 2):

The dragon is a female, because as Valk says in the second movie, most nests have a queen. Hers is a king, and most kings have a special ability about them but this queen doesn't, she is just large.